# Jquery validation- assigning group in html markup

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Is there a way to assign or define group within html markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the data tags in HTML.

```
<a href="#" data-group=""></a>
```

Comment: I was thinking to use that. Do you know if it works? Anyways I will give a try

Comment: Do I just need to assign group name to data-group?? Like data-group="search"

Comment: @emphaticsunshine that's exactly what he meant. It's good practice to use `data-` as a prefix for non-standard/non-existing attributes.